# Telling someone don't or telling someone not to

Tags: negation, reported-speech, quotation-marks

> I told Jim not to shout.
>
> I told Jim don't shout.

Could anyone possibly tell me what is the difference between these? And which one would you rather use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first is *indirect discourse*: it reports the content of what you said, not your actual words.

The second is *direct discourse*, reporting your actual words, and should be pointed with quotation marks:

> I told Jim, "Don’t shout!"

Comment: If your _actual_ words to Jim were "Don't shout.", you can quote them as @StoneyB said (you can use either form). Otherwise, you _must_ use the first form ("I told Jim not to shout."), as you don't want to misquote yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question: if I thought I had said something especially clever, I would quote it directly as in your second example.  If I simply wanted someone to understand what I told him, I'd use the indirect example.  Therefore, since I am a humble and self-effacing soul, I would prefer the usage in your first example.  :)